# Unity 3D (C#), my mouse detection is offset but i dont know why

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Okay, so i am trying to make a box that lights up when you hover over it, i have tried using the "OnMouseOver" function but it doesnt work, the boxes are each their own UI element, its just a rect transform with an Image component. Here is the script i am using, i used gizmos for the raycasting and the red boxes on the left, but for some reason, the mouse has to be wayyyy over to the side for it to show up, i want it to be on top of the box itself, the *55 in the script is because the size of the box is 55 in the gridlayout group i am using to store all the objects.

Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SlotScript : MonoBehaviour
{


    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.mousePosition.x > (transform.position.x*55) - 20 && Input.mousePosition.x < (transform.position.x*55) + 20)
        {
            if (Input.mousePosition.y > (transform.position.y*55) - 20 && Input.mousePosition.y < (transform.position.y*55) + 20)
            {
                Debug.Log("White");
                gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/Rack/WhiteBox");
            }
            else
            {
                gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/Rack/DarkBox");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/Rack/DarkBox");
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawCube(transform.position, transform.lossyScale * 55);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, GameObject.Find("Cursor").transform.position);
    }
}
```

The left is the scene view while the right is the game view
Image:
[image]

Comment: The mouse co-ordinates and the game object co-ordinates might exist in different scopes. Find out what scope each are in and convert one of them to the other one:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/696661/converting-world-coordinates-to-screen-coordinates.html

Comment: you also arent using the mouse position as it is, thefore it will offset